# Extract substrings from field sql/presto

Tags: mysql, sql, database, presto, amazon-athena

I have columns in my database that contains values separated by /. I am trying to extract certain values from columns and create new row with them.

Example of data look like below;

```
user/values2/class/year/subject/18/9/2000291.csv
holiday/booking/type/1092/1921/1.csv
drink/water/juice/1/232/89.json
drink/water1/soft/90091/2/89.csv
car/type/1/001/1.json
game/mmo/1/2/3.json
```

I want to extract the last 3 numbers from the data e.g., from

```
user/values2/class/year/subject/18/9/2000291.csv
```

I want

```
x = 18
y = 9
z = 200291
```

and display these are new field in the table.

I have been researching and playing around with presto queries but couldn't figure out how I can achieve what I want. I wrote the query below but can't get it to work.

```
SELECT origin
         split_part(origin, '.' & '/', 1) as z,
         split_part(origin, '.' & '/', 2) as y,
         split_part(origin, '.' & '/', 3) as x,
FROM "data_customer";
```

**EDITED**

Current table

[image]

Desired outcome

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presto code:

```
with your_data as(
select * from (values
'user/values2/class/year/subject/18/9/2000291.csv',
'holiday/booking/type/1092/1921/1.csv',
'drink/water/juice/1/232/89.json',
'drink/water1/soft/90091/2/89.csv',
'car/type/1/001/1.json',
'game/mmo/1/2/3.json'
)s (origin)
)

select s.origin, origin_splitted[3] x, origin_splitted[2]  y, regexp_extract(origin_splitted[1],'\d*') z
from
(
select s.origin, reverse(split(s.origin,'/')) origin_splitted from your_data s
)s
```

Result:

```
origin  x   y   z
user/values2/class/year/subject/18/9/2000291.csv    18  9   2000291
holiday/booking/type/1092/1921/1.csv              1092  1921    1
drink/water/juice/1/232/89.json                      1  232 89
drink/water1/soft/90091/2/89.csv                 90091  2   89
car/type/1/001/1.json                              1    1   1
game/mmo/1/2/3.json                                1    2   3
```

apply the same regexp_extract to x and y columns if necessary or another split can be applied instead of regexp_extract, hope you got the idea

Comment: The origin is a field name that contains those values on separate columns. Sorry should have made this clear.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, please see edited session. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @Adamkhan What the difference does it make? could you please explain. It looks like you have origin column and you need to extract values from it and I did exectly the same. Just replace my your_data CTE with your table and voila

Comment: ```with data_customer as(
select * from (values)s (origin))``` Should I only select from values and not put the proceeding data e.g., 'user/values2/class/year/subject/18/9/2000291.csv'

Comment: @Adamkhan \d in regexp means digit.

Comment: How about the *

Comment: @Adamkhan * is a quantifier, means any number of times. You can try to modify regexp, there are number of ways to achieve the same using regular expressions. Read more here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html

Comment: Thanks, your solution helps a lot :)