# select stack() UDTF in Impala

Tags: impala

In Hive I can sample data using stack() UDTF like this:

```
with students as ( 
select stack(5,
1,'Vikrant',
2,'Abhishek',
3,'Ragesh',
4,'Valeriy',
5,'Swarna') as (id, name)
)

select * from students;
```

In Presto [I can use values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507332/2700344) for the same.

How can I do it in Impala EXCEPT using [multiple selects for each row and UNION ALL like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246619/2700344)?

Comment: `UNION ALL` with a CTE is how I would write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I studied, **Impala does not support table generating functions yet**. No stack, [no lateral view explode](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/lateral-view-explode-in-impala/td-p/79326), [no UDTF are possible](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_udf.html) in Impala unfortunately.

So, the only way is this:

```
with students as ( 
select 1 as id,'Vikrant'  as name union all
select 2 as id,'Abhishek' as name union all
select 3 as id,'Ragesh'   as name union all
select 4 as id,'Valeriy'  as name union all
select 5 as id,'Swarna'   as name
)

select * from students;
```